# How to set the date range correctly (to the minute, seconds) in order to receive letters from the email

Tags: imap, date-range, mail-server

```
Imports EAGetMail

Public Sub ReceiveMail( _
    ByVal sServer As String, _
    ByVal sUserName As String, _
    ByVal sPassword As String, _
    ByVal bSSLConnection As Boolean _
)
Dim oClient As New MailClient("TryIt")

Dim oServer As New MailServer(sServer, _
    sUserName, sPassword, bSSLConnection, _
    ServerAuthType.AuthLogin, ServerProtocol.Imap4)

Try
    oClient.Connect(oServer)

    Dim options As GetMailInfosOptionType = GetMailInfosOptionType.ReadOnly
    options = options Or GetMailInfosOptionType.DateRange
    options = options Or GetMailInfosOptionType.OrderByDateTime

    oClient.GetMailInfosParam.Reset()
    oClient.GetMailInfosParam.GetMailInfosOptions = options

    oClient.GetMailInfosParam.SubjectContains = "test"
    oClient.GetMailInfosParam.SenderContains = "support"
    oClient.GetMailInfosParam.DateRange.SINCE = System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12)
    oClient.GetMailInfosParam.DateRange.BEFORE = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)  

    Dim infos() As MailInfo = oClient.GetMailInfos()
```

...

Comment: That's some code (I reformatted it for you, hope I got it right). But what's is the problem with the code?

Comment: IMAP Search does not support time specification, period.  If you want to narrow it down more precisely then the day, you'll have to fetch the metadata and do it client side.

Comment: That is, I need to get all the mails for the specified period, and then more accurately filter, I understood correctly?

Comment: You can use a search to get the IDs of the messages on the day you want (note IMAP is also not really TZ aware, so you may need to fetch an extra day), then fetch their INTERNALDATE, and do the fine filtering on the client, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMAP Search does not support time specification, period. If you want to narrow it down more precisely then the day, you'll have to fetch the metadata and do it client side.

Solution: You can use a search to get the IDs of the messages on the day you want (note IMAP is also not really TZ aware, so you may need to fetch an extra day), then fetch their INTERNALDATE, and do the fine filtering on the client, yes. – Max